# Derivatives of the Jacobian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, optimization, partial-derivative

For a given function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $, the jacobian matrix is defined as :
\begin{equation}\label{fourth_3_equation}
    J(x) = \frac{\partial f_{k}}{\partial x_{j}} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{1}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{n}}\\
 \vdots & &\vdots\\
\frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{1}} & \cdots  &\frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{n}}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

I want to know please what is the first and the second derivative of the jacobian and how can one calculates it.

Thank you.

Comment: Derivative with respect to what?

Comment: The function $J$ has domain $n$-vectors but codomain $m\timesn$-matrices, so it's derivatives are gonna be multidimensional arrays. Having said that, simply use definition using linear expansion of first order.

Comment: @eyeballfrog derivative with respect to tall elements  $x_{j}$.

Comment: @WilliamM. Is there please any references where i can find the formula that i have to use /apply to get the derivatives ?

Answer (score 0):

In indices notation, you have $J_{ij}=\dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$, and $m\times n$ dimensional matrix.

Then $\dfrac{\partial J_{ij}}{\partial x_{\lower{0.25ex}k}}=\dfrac{\partial^2 f_i}{\partial x_{\lower{0.25ex}k}~\partial x_{j}}$

This is a $m\times n\times n$ dimensional tensor.

$$\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial x} = \left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial^2 f_1(x)}{\partial x_1~^2}&\cdots&\frac{\partial^2 f_1(x)}{\partial x_1 \partial x_n}\\\vdots &\ddots&\vdots\\\frac{\partial^2 f_m(x)}{\partial x_1~^2}&\cdots&\frac{\partial^2 f_m(x)}{\partial x_1 \partial x_n}\end{matrix}~\middle\vert~\cdots~\middle\vert~\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial^2 f_1(x)}{\partial x_n \partial x_1}&\cdots&\frac{\partial^2 f_1(x)}{\partial x_n~^2}\\\vdots &\ddots&\vdots\\\frac{\partial^2 f_m(x)}{\partial x_n \partial x_1}&\cdots&\frac{\partial^2 f_m(x)}{\partial x_n~^2}\end{matrix}\right]$$

Subsequent derivatives are similarly concatenated, as higher dimensional tensors.